# Multiple Objects don't move correctly in same armature

Tags: animation, objects, rigging, armature

I made a own model for my game, everything worked well despite some difficulties, but now I have a problem. My mesh is built up by seperate objects, such as teeth, eyes and the body. I already made an armature and now the upper teeth and the eyes don't move correctly.

[image: fig 1]

[image: fig 2. the eyes and the upper teeth move "too fast". No problems with the other teeth]

I tried putting all objects into a group and also just made a single object (Although it's not an option for my model since I need different materials for these objects in the game itself), but still this problem occurs. Already checked the vertex groups, the weight and everything but couldn't find anything suspicious.

This is a nasty stop for my project, hopefully you guys can help me somehow?

EDIT:
.blend file:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/gksxei1emlgp0ta/watcher_mesh_rigging1.blend

Cheers to all,
Johann

Comment: Can you upload the .blend file?

Comment: Looks like a problem with weights to me at first sight, but like Todd said, we would need the blend file to tell

Comment: Thank you for your response. I uploaded the file, also edited in the original question.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/gksxei1emlgp0ta/watcher_mesh_rigging1.blend

Comment: What parts of the head are intended to be deformable/stretch capable ... and which are not?  Are the teeth stretchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your support, I did it.

I think it were in fact, the vertex weight, since there still was weigth from nearby bones on the skull and the jaw bone. I resetted the whole groups and edited the weight of every bone for the skull and the jaw, so it's mainly on 100% for the resperctive bones and 0 for the others.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Upper teeth and eyes weight was set 100% only to the skull bone and lower teeth was set 100% only to the jaw bone.

Thanks again for your help!
Johann

Answer (score 0):

- Consider adding un upper jaw teeth bone.  The weights will be [1.0] for teeth.
- If your eyes in the model rotate you will also need to add minimum 2 bones for those.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried adding another bone for the teeth, but no matter what parent this bone had (and weight), it didn't work. Meanwhile I made another approach. I post my answer in minutes.